# Consultation about android phone number

Tags: android

i try to get my phone number like this:

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

but i get null

how to fix it ? and how to get Provider Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Some vendor do not save Phone number in SIM. This work fine in some countries.

Its better to ask user to enter the phone number.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony) for getLine1Number() says this method will return null if the number is "unavailable", but it does not say when the number might be unavailable.

To get the provider name

Look the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName%28%29).

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```